# How to avoid multiple rows from join query

Tags: mysql

i have the below query:

```
Select * from table1,table2 where table1.id!=table2.itid
```

when i run this query it gives multiple rows.

Table1:

```
id itemname
1    xyz
2    abc
3    dskd
4    asda
```

Table 2:

```
  itemdetail  table1_id
   jkj         2
   hud         3
```

so i want the below `output`:

```
id   itemname
1     xyz
4     asda
```

how can i do this?

Comment: Could you expand your question a little? Like showing a part of your tables and what you'd like to get? It is logical that this query returns many rows

Comment: pleae check my updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
   SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE table1.id NOT IN(SELECT table2.itid FROM table2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, but I'm not sure of the syntax right now:

```
Select * from table1,table2 where table1.id NOT IN table2.itid
```